# Perform a mask on variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I have some inputs values (32-bit unsigned integer) defined as follow, with their associated identifier, in a file :

```
var=0x000000001
var1=0x000000002
var2=0x000000004
var3=0x000000008
toto=0x000000010
titi=0x000000020
tata=0x000000040   
toto1=0x000000080  
toto2=0x000000100
toto3=0x000000200
titi2=0x000000400
titi3=0x000000800   
tito0=0x000001000
tito1=0x000002000
tito2=0x000004000
tito3=0x000008000
tito4=0x000010000
```

I would like to implement a second function name GetConfig() which must return an uint32 value. Based on this value, I would to quote the associated variable. If I enter 300 I should display toto2 toto3.

```
function Config()
{
vartest=$1

    if [ -f $file ]; then
        while read lines  
        do  
            value=${lines##*=}
            mask=$(($vartest & $value))
            echo $mask
        done < $file
    else
        exitError 101
    fi  
}
```

If I enter ./script Config 3840 I obtain :

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
256
512
1024
2048
0
0
0
0
0
```

I can easily display toto2 toto3 titi5 titii, but if I enter ./script Config 4812, I obtain :

```
0
0
4
8
0
0
64
128
0
512
0
0
4096
0
0
0
0
```

This result can not allows me to display var1 titi titii test1

I am not sure to be clear but I am really currently blocked on this mask issue.

Thank in advance

Comment: First, I do not see the relationship from value 300 and the values of toto2 and toto3. Second, have you realized that those entries (toto2 and toto3) in the file have no equal sign `=`? Third, some values in the file has no associated an identfier (those below titii).

Comment: Jdamian, I edited my first post. In the file equal sign are present and all variable have an associated name which could be change if necessary. The relationship from value 300 and the values of toto2 and toto3 is quite simple. toto2=0x000000100 and toto3=0x000000300. This is the reason why if 300 is specified to my function I would like to identify toto2 and toto3. For instance : ./script Config 300 ==> Returns : toto2 toto3

Comment: Please explain me that "quite simple relationship" which I do not understand. In your file toto3 is not 0x300 but 0x200.

Comment: The masks you print *do* add up to 4812. What is the problem? Are you trying to print the variable name, rather than the value?

Comment: I guess it's your input which is wrong. try : `vartest=$( printf "0x%09d" $1` )

Comment: Jdamian, toto3 is 0x200 and toto2 is 0x100. A dedicated function returns 0x300 and it is a "sum" of 200+100. I recognize that it can seem quite strange.. But I can not modify the input value.

Comment: Chepner, when I enter 4812 the problem is that I obtain values which correspond to u32var2, u32var3, u32tata, u32toto1, u32toto3 and u32tito instead of u32var1, u32toto, u32toto3 and u32tito2. At the same time, I am trying to print the variable name yes

Comment: @SnP, in your question text you always said '300', not '0x300'. The Arithmetic Expressions in `bash` include octal, hexa and decimal values. Then the value `$(( 300 & 0x200 ))` is not the same than `$(( 0x300 & 0x200 ))` and `$(( 0300 & 0x200 ))`.

Comment: @Jadamian thank you for your clarification. I made jumble between octal and hexa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem statement isn't very clear but I hope this snippet can help put you back on track.  The real meat is in using `${lines%=*}` to obtain the key corresponding to the value in this `lines`.

```
Config() {
    vartest=$1
    if [ -f $file ]; then
        while read lines
        do
            value=${lines##*=}
            test $(($vartest & $value)) = 0 && continue
            echo "${lines%=*}"
        done < $file
    else
        exitError 101
    fi
}

file=/dev/stdin
Config 3840 <<':'
    var=0x000000001
    var1=0x000000002
    var2=0x000000004
    var3=0x000000008
    toto=0x000000010
    titi=0x000000020
    tata=0x000000040
    toto1=0x000000080
    toto2=0x000000100
    toto3=0x000000200
    titi2=0x000000400
    titi3=0x000000800
    tito0=0x000001000
    tito1=0x000002000
    tito2=0x000004000
    tito3=0x000008000
    tito4=0x000010000
:
```

Test run:

```
toto2
toto3
titi2
titi3
```

I would expect a more-useful function to not require the values in a file; this incidentally also illustrates how to put them in a here document (I did some weird stuff to not have to change those parts of your function).

Comment: thank you for this example. I modified it in order to solve my problem. Finally, the efficient implementation is a mix between Duffydake and your solution.